# Liferay search-iterator only showing first 11 pages in page selector

Tags: java, html, jsp, liferay

I have a liferay search-container constaining thousands of results with a search-iterator attached. On the page selector dropdown it will only show the first 11 pages

[image: First 11 pages]

Clicking on a later page (I chose page 11) it expands to show the next 10 pages

[image: Next set of pages]

Selecting further pages only ever show 20 pages worth of page numbers (ie. selecting page 40 will show page numbers 30 through 50).

**How do I change this to show all pages from 1 to 161?**

I have tried changing the search-iterator [type](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/taglibs/util-taglib/liferay-ui/search-iterator.html) as well as adding a seperate [search-paginator](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/taglibs/util-taglib/liferay-ui/search-paginator.html), niether of which fixed the issue.

I have also tried changing the search delta, which doesn't have any effect on the page selector.

Here is the JSP code for creating the search-container:

```
<% rowChecker = new RowChecker(renderResponse); %>

<liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="${itemsSearchContainer}" rowChecker="<%=rowChecker%>" total="${itemsSearchContainer.total}">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${itemsSearchContainer.results}"/>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="item" keyProperty="itemKey" className="ItemDetail">
        <%-- Hidden: liferay-ui:search-container-column-text columns --%>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an property that configure the pages to see on that select so if you change that the number will grow of the page displayed

```
Set the maximum number of pages available above and below the currently displayed page.

Defaults:
search.container.page.iterator.max.pages=10
```

Comment: Thank you, I will add that this only works for portal.properties which get loaded before any portlets get loaded.